# Excel - How to fix letter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, formula, extend

I have a column B with numbers and I want my row 2 to be 1-B3, 1-B4, 1-B5 and so forth.

If I type in =1-B3 and extend it to the right it becomes 1-C3, 1-D3 and so forth.

If I type in =1=$B3 and extend it to the right it just stays 1-B3.

How do I lock the letter B so that only the number will increase when I extent it to the right?

Comment: `=1-INDEX($B:$B, COLUMN (C1))`

Comment: `="1-B"&COLUMN(C1)` (or `=ROW(1:1)&"-B"&COLUMN(C1)` if you want to be able to copy down and alter the prefix as well)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. So you can't do that in a single, manual copy or range extension.

You could (as JvdV suggested) write a more complex formula, that will transpose on copy/extend. But I'm not sure if that's what you're trying to learn.
You could also write vb to automate the construction your formula. Again though, I'm pretty sure that's also not what you're asking.

Assuming you're just looking for a simple manual solution to what you're trying to do:

1. Enter the formula =1=$B3 in a cell in any EMPTY column
   *Doesn't matter where that cell is*
2. Copy/extend that cell down the COLUMN to match all your column B values
3. Select the entire suite and Copy
4. Select the target starting cell, in your target row
5. Right Click >> Paste Special
6. Select Paste Formulas and Check Transpose >> Click Ok

You can now of course delete the 'temporary' column of formula